# Changing the appearance and user authentication in Owncloud

Tags: owncloud

I installed owncloud 10.0.8 on centos 7 and everything went well. Since I needed user authentication via Active Directory I installed “LDAP Integration” from the market and suddenly the background and the name change to “Custom Cloud”. Now despite changing the background file and some change in “/lib/private/legacy/defaults.php” file nothing changes.

What should I do to apply my changes and what is “Custom Cloud”?
Is it correct to use “LDAP Integration” app for user authentication via Active Directory ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Owncloud. In Nextcloud the theming can be easily done in the webui and LDAP is already included. Nextcloud is faster and has a lot more features and is fully open source. So I suggest that you try this instead.